# value printing from child go routine after defer

Tags: go, concurrency

I am spwanning 5 worker pools from my driver code, and returning errors from worker pools. In my main, i have another go routine (go routine A , added comment on top of that go routine)listening on errors.
But by the time data is picked from my error channel, my defer statement is getting executed. But i can still see logs from go routine A .

```
func ....{
var requests []Req
        err := json.Unmarshal(Data, &requests)
        if err != nil {
            log.WithError(err).Errorf("Invalid data passed for flag type %v", proto.CreateFlagReq_SET_OF.String())
            return err
        }
        f.Manager.TaskChan = make(chan Req, 100)
        f.Manager.ErrorChan = make(chan error, 100)

        for i := 0; i < f.Manager.WorkerCount; i++ {
            f.Manager.Wg.Add(1)
           //AddToSetOfcustomers just validates before addigg to redis
            go f.Manager.Work(ctx, f.redisPool.AddToSetOfcustomers, i)
        }

        for _, request := range requests {
            f.Manager.TaskChan <- request
        }
        close(f.Manager.TaskChan)

        var errors error
        **//go routine A**
        go func() {
            for {
                select {
                case err ,ok:= <- f.Manager.ErrorChan:
                    if ok{
                        errors = multierror.Append(errors, err)
                        log.Errorf("got erro1r %v",errors)
                    }else{
                        log.Info("returning")
                        return
                    }

                }
            }
        }()
        f.Manager.Wg.Wait()

        defer log.Errorf("blhgsgh   %v %v",len(f.Manager.ErrorChan),errors)
        return errors
}


func (m *Manager) Work(ctx context.Context, fn func(string, string, string) error, workerNumber int) {
log.Infof("spawnning worker %v", workerNumber)
defer m.Wg.Done()
defer log.Info("done working")
for {
    select {
    case t, ok := <-m.TaskChan:
        if ok {
            err := fn(t.CustomerName, t.CustomerId, t.Feature)
            if err != nil {
                log.Infof("pushing error from %v",workerNumber)
                m.ErrorChan <- err
            }
        } else {
            return
        }
    case <-ctx.Done():
        log.Infof("closing channel %v", ctx.Err())
        return
    }
}
```

}

And my logs go like this

info spawnning worker 0
2022/03/14 01:51:44  info spawnning worker 2
2022/03/14 01:51:44  info spawnning worker 1
2022/03/14 01:51:44  info done working
2022/03/14 01:51:44  info done working
2022/03/14 01:51:44  info spawnning worker 3
2022/03/14 01:51:44  info done working
2022/03/14 01:51:44  info spawnning worker 4
2022/03/14 01:51:44  info done working
2022/03/14 01:51:44  info pushing error from 0
2022/03/14 01:51:44  info done working
**2022/03/14 01:51:44 error blhgsgh   0 

2022/03/14 01:51:44 error got erro1r 1 error occurred:
* myError**

I kind of suspect defer got executed, then my main go routine finished and then return got executed, but what i can i do to propagate the error i am appending from multiErrors before returning?

if i try to synchronise go routine A and my main go routine(the one where i call defer) using channels, it becomes blocking.Help appretiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified your code in [the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Ohv2lUJchsw).

You appear to be assuming that when `f.Manager.Wg.Wait()` returns all errors will have been processed. However the errors are being processed in a separate goroutine (`**//go routine A**`) and you are not waiting for that to complete -- in fact because you do not close `f.Manager.ErrorChan` the goroutine never completes.

The simplest way to resolve this is to wait for the goroutine to exit before returning from the function. The below example ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/_4MG7jCqMEE)) uses a channel to do this but you could also use a `WaitGroup` if you prefer.

```
var errors []error
errDone := make(chan struct{})
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case err, ok := <-errorChan:
            if ok {
                errors = append(errors, err)
                log.Printf("got error %v", errors)
            } else {
                log.Printf("returning")
                close(errDone)
                return
            }
        }
    }
}()
wg.Wait()

// Everything sending to errorChan is now done so we can safely close the channel
close(errorChan)
<-errDone // Wait for error handling goroutine to complete
```

Note that [`defer`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Defer_statements) runs "immediately before the surrounding function returns". Any goroutines that you have started can outlive the function (they are not automatically stopped).